# How to call onended event for videos created when the popup is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I am creating a video element onload event of a particular popup, is there a way i can call the **onended** event for the created video when the video ends.

my code for creating video element onload is as follows

Dynamic code

```
require ("connect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows > 0) {

        $video_div = 0;
        $hide = 0;



        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $video_id = $row['id'];

            $url = $row['url'];

            $url_value = "video.php?name=" . $url;
            $filename = $row['name'];
            $user_type = $row['usertype'];
            $url = array($url);
            if ($user_type == 0) {
                $user_category = "Prospective User";
            }
            if ($user_type == 1) {
                $user_category = "Admin User";
            }
            if ($user_type == 2) {
                $user_category = "Actual Customer";
            }


            $video_div = $video_div + 1;
            $video_dive = "video_div" . $video_div;


            //click event to load colorbox
            echo '<a  class="inline" href="#'. $video_dive.'"  id="'.$url_value.'">
            <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" width="50" height="50"   > 
            </a>';
            //div to show vide element through jquery
            echo '<div id="' . $video_dive . '"    > </div>';

       }
} else {
        echo "There are no uploaded videos";
    }
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".inline", this).colorbox({

            inline : true,

            width : '650px',
            //load function that opens the popup
            onLoad : function() {

                href_value = $(this).attr("href");
                id_value = $(this).attr("id");

                techi = {
                    "techOrder" : ["flash", "html5"]
                };

                //to reder video element insid the div
                $(href_value).html('<video id="player" data-my_videoid="1"   class="videocall video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"  preload="auto" poster="images/video_img.png" width="640" height="360" controls data-setup="' + techi + '"><source src="' + id_value + '" type="video/mp4"  /> <p class="vjs-no-js">To view the video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p> </video>');

                var myPlayer = videojs('player');
                myPlayer.load();
                $(href_value).show();

            }
});
}):
```

I am creating the video element on load event of a popup dynamically

The above is called onLoad event of a popup ,  onended event must be fired once the video has ended

Is there a way to trigger onend event while the video has ended

I would like to set the ended event but i have no idea how to trigger the event since i am creating the video element at the time of opening the colorbox popup using jquery

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to call "onended", but you can add a callback to it to do something when the video has ended. Is that your goal?

Comment: I would suggest using the javascript setup for your player.  In the videojs function you can set the `ended` event.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("video").on("ended", function() {
            $.ajax({
              // set your params here
          });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Add a callback with `$("video").on("ended", ...)`.

UPDATE: Sorry, removed some unnecessary code. Refresh the page.
UPDATE2: More on $.ajax, [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: i am declaring the video only when the popup is open

Comment: It's still ambiguous what you want to acheive, is the pop-up a separate browser window or you create an overlay-like div with a video tag in it?

Comment: its a overlay like div with video tag created when popup is open

Comment: Then it shouldn't be much problem to resolve this issue. What are you trying to do after the video ended? Close the "popup"? Remove the div.

Comment: i need to store the dynamic value from the video in the  database

Comment: Well, then make an ajax call ($.ajax) as the callback of $("video").on("ended", function() { do some ajax });

Comment: ya , i just need to trigger the video end event .

Comment: $("video").on("ended", ...) is not being called